# Passing multiple arguments with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA doesn't work with more than the first parameter. Here is my sub header: `Sub filterPivotTables(ParamArray argumentsArray() As Variant , sheetName As String,pivotTableName As String,pivotField As String)`

However, when I change the sub header to this: `Sub filterPivotTables(ParamArray argumentsArray() As Variant)` it works.

Is there a reason why I can’t pass in more than one parameter? How would you pass in more than one parameter? Thanks

Comment: How/Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParamArray` must be the *last* argument in the procedure declaration:

```
Sub filterPivotTables(sheetName As String, pivotTableName As String, pivotField As String, ParamArray argumentsArray() As Variant)
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays) for a more thorough discussion of `ParamArray`.